# Pandasを使ってCSVの内容を出力するコードで、日本語で書いたヘッダーの部分と数値の位置がずれてしまう

Tags: python, python3, windows, pandas

csvとして保存したデータをpandasを使ってPythonで出力するコードを書きました。
しかし、いざ結果を出力してみると日本語で書いたヘッダーの部分と数値の位置がずれてしまいます。

触っているうちにわかったことは、ヘッダーを英語でcsvのヘッダーを英語で入力するときれいに揃った表ができるということです。ヘッダーを日本語できれいにそろえることはできませんか？また自分はwindowsをつかっています。これが問題ということはありますでしょうか？

**csvのコード**:

```
名前,国語,数学,英語,理科,社会
A太,83,89,76,97,76
B介,66,93,75,88,76
C子,100,84,96,82,94
D郎,60,73,63,52,70
E美,92,62,84,80,78
F菜,96,92,94,92,90
```

**ソースコード**:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

print(df)
```

Comment: `pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)` としてから `print(df)` を実行してみると良いかもしれません。

Comment: 解決できました！pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)をコードに入れればいいんですね。大変有益な情報ありがとうございました。ついでにこれが必要なのは自分が使っているのがWindowsだからなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

@metropolis さんコメントで解決とのことで、それを基にコミュニティWikiとして回答。

質問時点での状況：

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
>>>
>>> print(df)
   名前   国語  数学  英語  理科  社会
0  A太   83  89  76  97  76
1  B介   66  93  75  88  76
2  C子  100  84  96  82  94
3  D郎   60  73  63  52  70
4  E美   92  62  84  80  78
5  F菜   96  92  94  92  90
```

コメントの適用結果：

```
>>> pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)
>>> print(df)
  名前  国語  数学  英語  理科  社会
0  A太    83    89    76    97    76
1  B介    66    93    75    88    76
2  C子   100    84    96    82    94
3  D郎    60    73    63    52    70
4  E美    92    62    84    80    78
5  F菜    96    92    94    92    90
```

コメント関連の仕様記述先：
[Unicode formatting - Options and settings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#unicode-formatting)
表示性能が2倍くらい遅くなりますとか、幅が曖昧な文字についての追加オプションの説明等が書かれています。